Windows Server 2022: FSRM crashes when adding notification threshold in quota
When I trying to add notification threshold to quota in File server resource manager:

The File server resource manager (FSRM) crashes with message:

Type"Microsoft.Storage.SrmMmc.CannotCreateSettingsWMIObjectException" in assembly "SrmGui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is not marked as serializable



I get a similar error even when creating a new quota.
So how to solve this issue?
